# Is there a way to switch my keyboard layout based on a trigger?

Tags: windows-7, windows, automation, keyboard-layout

On my latop, Windows 7 x64 automatically detects when I am at the office and when I am at home and switches the external monitor layout. I also use different ISPs at home then at work (naturally different IP ranges). At home, I also connect to a specific wifi network, while at the office the connection is wired.

**Is it possible to automatically switch the keyboard layout** to A when I am at home, based on one of the triggers above? In every other situation (office, on the street, etc) I would like to use layout B.

I know it [can't be done via command line](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hu/w7itprogeneral/thread/e80ab09c-8ff5-4572-939b-0dd32fdbea01), but there might be another way to switch it.

Answer (score 0):

This might provide some clues for how to do it via a command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/goglobal/bb964650(en-us).aspx

Once you've worked that bit out, I would then use the task scheduler to run the command to change the keyboard layout when the right action occurs (e.g. connect to home wireless network)

Answer (score 0):

Another way might be to use AutoHotKey to remap the keyboard. That would work at a different level to changing the layout through windows, but could do the trick. You could trigger that through task scheduler as well.